# gethostbyaddr() raises UnicodeDecodeError in Python 3

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to build a Django project with Python 3.4.1. `manage.py runserver` raises a UnicodeDecodeException.

How can this be resolved? See the below (trimmed) traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\socketserver.py", line 429, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 121
, in server_bind
    super(WSGIServer, self).server_bind()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 50, in server_bind
    HTTPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\server.py", line 135, in server_bind
    self.server_name = socket.getfqdn(host)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\socket.py", line 460, in getfqdn
    hostname, aliases, ipaddrs = gethostbyaddr(name)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcf in position 12: invalid
 continuation byte
```

Per request, my hostname:

```
C:\Users\AnatoliyVik>hostname
AnatoliyVik-ПК
```

Comment: Will you please check your hostname? type `hostname` on console and add it to question.

Comment: Did you try using Python 2.7 instead ?

Comment: I don't think JetBrains/PyCharm is compatible with Django 1.7 - several commands are missing like migrate, makemigrations. Try generating the project via the command line and import it later into PyCharm

Comment: Answers shouldn't be edited into the question -- they should be added **as answers**, and voted on / accepted. Similarly, if updating the question to respond to comments, make sure that the question remains readable on its own, without needing to read comments before it can be understood. If you want a shorter response to a comment, just add that as a comment itself.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the hostname to no longer include Cyrillic symbols resolves the problem.

Thanks to @Lafada for the guidance.

Comment: Was the solution, then, to change the hostname, or did you find an alternate workaround which allowed the code to work with non-UTF-8 hostnames?

Comment: I'm just changed the hostname